# Newly created weblogic domain is not starting

Tags: weblogic, application-server, system-administration

I am creating a new domain in weblogic and was successful in creating that. When I run it there is no error and the command prompt shows that it is started successfully. But when I look it in browser I get Error 404--Not Found. Please help me.

Here is the log:

```
starting weblogic with Java version:
java version "1.5.0_22"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_22-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.5.0_22-b03, mixed mode)
Starting WLS with line:
C:\bea\JDK150~1\bin\java -client   -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -
XX:PermSize=48m  -XX:MaxPermSize=128m  -Xverify:none  -da -Dplatform.home=C:\bea
\WEBLOG~1 -Dwls.home=C:\bea\WEBLOG~1\server -Dwli.home=C:\bea\WEBLOG~1\integrati
on  -Dweblogic.management.discover=true  -Dwlw.iterativeDev= -Dwlw.testConsole=
-Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole= -Dweblogic.ext.dirs=C:\bea\patch_weblogic924\profiles\
default\sysext_manifest_classpath -Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer -Djava.security.po
licy=C:\bea\WEBLOG~1\server\lib\weblogic.policy   weblogic.Server
<Dec 30, 2011 12:20:01 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000395> <Following
 extensions directory contents added to the end of the classpath:
C:\bea\weblogic92\platform\lib\p13n\p13n-schemas.jar;C:\bea\weblogic92\platform\
lib\p13n\p13n_common.jar;C:\bea\weblogic92\platform\lib\p13n\p13n_system.jar;C:\
bea\weblogic92\platform\lib\wlp\netuix_common.jar;C:\bea\weblogic92\platform\lib
\wlp\netuix_schemas.jar;C:\bea\weblogic92\platform\lib\wlp\netuix_system.jar;C:\
bea\weblogic92\platform\lib\wlp\wsrp-common.jar>
<Dec 30, 2011 12:20:01 PM IST> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000377> <Starting We
bLogic Server with Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM Version 1.5.0_22-b03 from Sun Micr
osystems Inc.>
<Dec 30, 2011 12:20:02 PM IST> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141107> <Version: WebLog
ic Server 9.2 MP4  Thu Jul 22 09:38:14 BST 2010 1350494 >
<Dec 30, 2011 12:20:05 PM IST> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000215> <Loaded Lice
nse : C:\bea\license.bea>
<Dec 30, 2011 12:20:05 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server st
ate changed to STARTING>
<Dec 30, 2011 12:20:05 PM IST> <Info> <WorkManager> <BEA-002900> <Initializing s
elf-tuning thread pool>
<Dec 30, 2011 12:20:05 PM IST> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170019> <The serve
r log file C:\bea\user_projects\domains\base_domain2\base_domain2\servers\AdminS
erver\logs\AdminServer.log is opened. All server side log events will be written
 to this file.>
<Dec 30, 2011 12:20:08 PM IST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090082> <Security initia
lizing using security realm myrealm.>
<Dec 30, 2011 12:20:10 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server st
ate changed to STANDBY>
<Dec 30, 2011 12:20:10 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server st
ate changed to STARTING>
<Dec 30, 2011 12:20:12 PM IST> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170027> <The serve
r initialized the domain log broadcaster successfully. Log messages will now be
broadcasted to the domain log.>
<Dec 30, 2011 12:20:12 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server st
ate changed to ADMIN>
<Dec 30, 2011 12:20:12 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server st
ate changed to RESUMING>
<Dec 30, 2011 12:20:13 PM IST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default"
 is now listening on 10.0.0.36:7002 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, http.>
<Dec 30, 2011 12:20:13 PM IST> <Warning> <Server> <BEA-002611> <Hostname "AlpsPS
O-2.bebo.com", maps to multiple IP addresses: 10.0.0.36, 127.0.0.1>
<Dec 30, 2011 12:20:13 PM IST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[
1]" is now listening on 127.0.0.1:7002 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, http.>
<Dec 30, 2011 12:20:13 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000331> <Started W
ebLogic Admin Server "AdminServer" for domain "base_domain2" running in Developm
ent Mode>
<Dec 30, 2011 12:20:13 PM IST> <Warning> <Server> <BEA-002611> <Hostname "localh
ost", maps to multiple IP addresses: 10.0.0.36, 127.0.0.1>
<Dec 30, 2011 12:20:13 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server st
ate changed to RUNNING>
<Dec 30, 2011 12:20:13 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000360> <Server st
arted in RUNNING mode>
```

Thank you
Ravi

Comment: Got the answer. It is in here start>All programs>BEA Product(BEA Home1)>User Projects>(name of newly created domain).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like from your log that you should be able to log into the WebLogic Server admin console by going to http://127.0.0.1:7002/console/login/LoginForm.jsp if you want to use a browser.  You'll just need to supply the username and password you put in when you created the domain.